# Is it possible to mount heavy objects to the exterior of a brick veneer home?

Tags: mounting, brick, veneer

I have a brick veneer home (single wythe) and would like to mount a outdoor fan that is about 60 lbs. and has a mounting plate and arm that has 4 bolt holes. In researching this project I have learned that you cannot mount directly to brick veneer homes such as mine because the brick cannot hold any weight beyond its own. Is there another option for attaching this fan to the exterior wall of my home that would meet code, would be safe, and would not damage my home?

Comment: It can probably hold the weight pulling straight down, but not any weight pulling away.   Should probably screw/bolt the plate to structural members(2x4s) behind the brick, but they can be a pain to find.